# react router: How can I change route view but doesn’t change url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In React Router 6, how can I change route view but doesn’t change url ?

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/a" element={<A />} />
  <Route path="/b" element={<B />} />
  <Route path="/c" element={<C />} />
</Router>
```

I want to change route view from A to B by using (react router 6)

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/b')
```

How can I set some options to let the user's browser address bar not change, keep /a, so that when user refresh the page, they can show route A.

Comment: What are you asking for? It's unclear what any issue is you are asking about. Can you clarify in more detail what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do what you're saying, you need to combine the two components `<A />` and `<B />` and handle which is showing on the page by `state`.

something like this:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/a" element={<AB />} />
  <Route path="/b" element={<B />} />
  <Route path="/c" element={<C />} />
</Router>
```

```
//AB component is:
function AB(){
  const [isB, setIsB] = useState(false);

  const navigateToB = () => setIsB(true);
  const navigateToA = () => setIsB(false);

  if(isB){
    return <B />;
  } else {
    return <A />;
  }
}
```

and there is possibility that you don't need the `/b` route at all